# get TypeError when post an array of files in Python using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror, telegram, telegram-bot

When I try to post an array of files in Python using requests, I get "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'".

In order to [send an album in Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto) from local, we need to provide an [array of files](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto), which contains file type. So I try:

```py
import requests

bot_token = '<BOT_TOKEN>'
send_to = 1234567890
data = {'chat_id': send_to}

album = [
    {'type': 'photo', 'media': 'test/foo.png'},
    {'type': 'photo', 'media': 'test/bar.png'},
]
for i in range(len(album)):
    album[i]['media'] = open(album[i]['media'], 'rb')
files = {'media': album}

test = requests.post(
    f'https://api.telegram.org/{bot_token}/sendMediaGroup',
    data=data, files=files)
```

When I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Games/GitHub/tgapi/test_album.py", line 87, in <module>
    data=data, files=files)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 504, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 169, in _encode_files
    body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata(new_fields)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\filepost.py", line 90, in encode_multipart_formdata
    body.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

P.S.:

- Adding `headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` into `requests.post` does not help.
- The code to send a single file is:

```py
files = {'photo': open('test/foo.png', 'rb')}

test = requests.post(
    f'https://api.telegram.org/{bot_token}/sendPhoto',
    data=data, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending in an array, your files variable is a dictionary, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Instead of adding the album from your loop to a dict key of media, just add it to an array and pass that in to your request

Comment: But the API of telegram seems to require a key of dict to be passed in POST request. However, send single file using this way works.

Answer (score 0):

**By referring to a popular package [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)**, I've figured out:

```py
import requests
import json

bot_token = '<BOT_TOKEN>'
send_to = 1234567890
data = {'chat_id': send_to}

album = [
    {'type': 'photo', 'media': 'foo.png'},
    {'type': 'photo', 'media': 'bar.png'},
]
files = {}
for i in range(len(album)):
    files[album[i]['media']] = open(album[i]['media'], 'rb')
data['media'] = json.dumps(album)
```

At this moment,

```py
data = {'chat_id': '345060487',
        'media': '[{"type": "photo", "media": "attach://foo.png"}, {"type": "photo", "media": "attach://bar.png"}]'
}
files = {
    'foo.png': open('test/foo.png', 'rb'),
    'bar.png': open('test/bar.png', 'rb'),
}
```

And finally this code will work:

```py
test = requests.post(
    f'https://api.telegram.org/{bot_token}/sendMediaGroup',
    data=data, files=files)
```

---

Note that, just like what is done in [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI), it's much better to **generate a random filename** by:

```py
import random
import string

def generate_random_filename(length=16):
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, length))
```